# Google Drive Api Files.Get giving weird response

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I am trying to use the google drive api for storing images and retrieving them when necessary.
Uploading to drive through javascript i working fine.
The problem is when i do files.get() request for a particular file-id the response coming is having data in some weird format.(looking into header it is gzip encoding). Can someone suggest how can i convert this to base64 so that i can display the image in the front end.

code for uploading the file:

```
const uploadFile = async (fileObject) => {
  const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
  bufferStream.end(fileObject.buffer);

  const { data } = await driveService.files.create({
    media: {
      mimeType: fileObject.mimeType,
      body: bufferStream,
    },
    requestBody: {
      name: fileObject.originalname,
      parents: [folderId],
    },
    fields: "id,name,webViewLink",
  });
  return data;
};
```

code for get request:

```
try{
    const id = req.body.id;
    driveService.files
      .get({
        fileId: id,
        alt: "media",
      })
      .then(
        function (response) {
          res.status(200).json(response);
        },
        function (reason) {
          throw reason;
        }
      );
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
    res.status(400).send(e.message);
  }
```

the response i am getting is something like this:
[Response Json for files.get request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmZeg.png)

I tried using Arraybuffers and then toString('base64'). but it did'nt helped.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `I tried using Arraybuffers and then toString('base64'). but it did'nt helped.`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a option to set response type while making the request.
The following changes solved the issue:

```
driveService.files.get(
  {
    fileId: id,
    alt: "media",
  },
  {
    responseType: "arraybuffer",
    encoding: null,
  },
  function (err, response) {
    if (err) throw err;
    else {
      var imageType = response.headers["content-type"];
      var base64 = Buffer.from(response.data, "utf8").toString("base64");
      var dataURI = "data:" + imageType + ";base64," + base64;

      res.status(200).json({ src: dataURI });
    }
```

now if i place this dataURI in src of an img element it works!!